# What happens to messages sent to an actor while it is suspended?

Tags: akka, actor, akka-supervision

Here is the situation, One my actors (A) is supervised by a Backoff supervisor (B).

The sequence of events that interest me is the following:

1. The system starts and everybody is happy
2. A fails while processing a message
3. B now considers A to be suspended until the backoff delay elapses
4. B receives some messages (MM) that he is meant to forward to A
5. The backoff delay elaspes and B restarts A
6. Everybody is happy again

**On step 4, what happens to those messages?**

Are they lost? Sent to dead-letters? stashed inside B somewhere, and sent to A when it restarts / resumes?

Now let's add another layer: A is not a standard Actor but an Actor with Stash.

**What happens to the stash of messages between the failure of A and its restart/resume?**
Is it discarded? Is it unstashed? Is it kept inside the stash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few experiments, I think I can answer both of my questions above:

**What happens to messages sent to an actor supervised by a Backoff supervisor between the moment the actor fails and the moment it is restarted?**

They are sent to `deadLetters()`

**What happens to the stash of messages between the failure of an actor and its restart?**

Nothing happens to the stash until the restart is actually attempted. When the restarting process starts, the `preRestart()` step of the stash calls `unstashAll()` to return all messages to the mailbox. Therefore messages are not lost, and not kept in the stash, but just unstashed and returned to the mailbox.